# Am I missing any type of JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql, db2

While writing some methods to simplify using joins in Java I realized joins can take many forms I didn't see before.

Am I missing any type?

```
-- Old-school inner/outer join, pre SQL-92
FROM t, u WHERE <predicate>

-- Inner joins
FROM t INNER JOIN u ON <predicate>
FROM t INNER JOIN u USING (<columns>)

-- Outer joins
FROM t LEFT OUTER JOIN u ON <predicate>
FROM t LEFT OUTER JOIN u USING (<columns>)
FROM t RIGHT OUTER JOIN u ON <predicate>
FROM t RIGHT OUTER JOIN u USING (<columns>)
FROM t FULL OUTER JOIN u ON <predicate>
FROM t FULL OUTER JOIN u USING (<columns>)

-- Cross join
FROM t CROSS JOIN u

-- Natural inner join
FROM t NATURAL INNER JOIN u

-- Natural outer joins
FROM t NATURAL LEFT OUTER JOIN u
FROM t NATURAL RIGHT OUTER JOIN u
FROM t NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN u

-- Union join (defined in SQL-92, deprecated in SQL:2003)
FROM t UNION JOIN u
```

Comment: You have left out `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Do you want to include the "APPLY" family of operations?

Comment: @Error_2646 Yes, I should. I totally forgot the `LATERAL`, `CROSS APPLY`, and `OUTER APPLY`. Thanks.

Comment: Is this MS-SQL, T-SQL, MySQL, Oracle SQL, or some other version of SQL? Some of them have their own brand of "JOIN"-esque terms.

Comment: @computercarguy I was trying to focus on the general SQL spec, rather than special cases. Anyway, can you name one of those special cases?

Comment: LEFT OUTER, RIGHT OUTER, there is also arrow syntax but you didn't specify the databases you are interested in.

Comment: Oracle has MINUS that works like a UNION, except that it removes all instances of the second query rows from the first query results. https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/minus.php

Comment: MINUS, UNION, etc. in Oracle are set operations, not joins.  (I don't think I've ever heard of the "UNION JOIN" mentioned in the post.)

Comment: @TheImpaler Join-Esque terms could be INTERSECT/EXCEPT in SQL Server.

Comment: UNION is not a join and it most definitely is not "deprecated"

Comment: @computercarguy: Oracle's `MINUS` is the what `EXCEPT` is in the SQL standard.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, and that's why the OP needs to specify which version of SQL they are using so they can get correct results for what they want to learn.

Comment: @computercarguy I tagged the datases I was thinking of: PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, and DB2.

Comment: @TheImpaler: if you want to concentrate on standard SQL, then you need to leave out `apply` that's Microsoft spelling of `lateral` (and every join can also be defined as a `lateral` join)

Comment: And what is your question? A question that answers itself, isn't really fit for Stackoverflow. You should probably just put the question in the question and add the join types as an answer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you. I wanted to know if I was missing any JOIN. This is actually quite important for my team.

Comment: Just an observation that "old school" joins aren't different join _types_, they're only different join _syntax_. They still create inner, outer, what have you, joins. I tried to let it go because dealing with them is likely relevant to your project, but I found I couldn't not comment. :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - `UNION JOIN` looks different from `UNION` http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/en/book_explicit_join_operations/page3.html. Looks like it unions the result of anti semi join in both direction

Comment: There is no `JOIN` syntax for them, but there are antijoins and semijoins.  Also, there are partitioned outer joins, using `PARTITION BY (expr) RIGHT OUTER JOIN...`. See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2177515.  Also, for my money, whatever you're doing, I wouldn't support `NATURAL` joins at all if I could avoid it.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak `PARTITION BY` is a new one for me. And yes, we ae discussing the inclusion of `NATURAL`; probably they don't offer any major benefits and multiple drawbacks. Thanks.

Comment: Missing for cross join: `FROM t, u` without a predicate, e.g., `SELECT t.col1, u.col2 FROM t, u`. Most of the times this happens it's an accident: the developer meant to add a predicate but forgot.

Comment: By the way, the `inner` and `outer` keywords are optional, so to me they are clutter and I never use them.

Answer (score 1):

Your list is complete, but just for your information `INNER JOIN` is equivalent to using just a plain `JOIN` in most flavors of SQL.